# Exception creating connection to... When not in local

Tags: java, rmi, remoteexception

I know the question have already been asked but i tried all the solutions on this website and others with no result...

My problem : 
I developp an application based in part on RMI, on localhost all is OK but when I start my application on my OVH Server, I can call a method on the server with RMI, but the server can't call a method on clients.
I get a RemoteException :

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.35; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:353)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.envoiMessageChat(Unknown Source)
at Client.controller.ChatController.keyPressed(ChatController.java:31)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to set the property hostname on the client :

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.1.35");
```

AND

on the server :

```
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "91.XXX.XXX.XXX");
```

but nothing too...

I tried to telnet the client from the server (On the registry's port i guess) : It works...

So, now I have no idea to solve the problem...

PS : Clients have a RMIRegistry too, because on my app, a client call a method on the server to call methods on all clients connected...

Comment: You don't need a Registry at the client to enable callbacks. Just have the client register its callback with the server. There isn't really such a thing in RMI as 'all clients connected', as there are no permanent RMI connections. It also looks like you're calling RMI methods from the event thread, which is wrong and will freeze the GUI.

Comment: There is a register method in my app, this one add client's ip to an arraylist of connected client ;) For my GUI i noticed that and i'll change in the future, but the app is in test version. The registry on client is necessary in this case, it's not really a callback but an other method !